# How to convert Oracle Error Messages to more user-friendly messages?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm writing a VB.Net application conncected to Oracle database.

When something goes wrong in the application, lets say, I try to insert a null value in a column which doesn't accept null values, Oracle raises an error which is handlded in the application using Try/Catch.

The error, messages are not always user friendly:

Example
Error Ora : 1400, An attempt was made to insert a NULL into the column "USER"."TABLE"."COLUMN"

That's not really the error message I would like to show to my user. The user is not expected to see the technical staff such as Oracle "user" or "table".

So what I'm trying to do is replacing:

- An attempt was made to insert a NULL into the column "USER"."TABLE"."COLUMN"

by

- The field "Column" should be filled.

Now, how to get the "Column" ? Of course I can analyse the string of the exception message and extract the Column but, but if my application is connected to another version of Oracle with slightly different exception strings, my application won't work.

Does anyone have an idea about a class to convert Oracle "technical" error messages to user-friendly messages ?

Thanks.

(The Null property is just an example, so **AllowDBNull = true** in a column is not really the solution)

Comment: My approach is to use validation in the user interface to prevent most DB errors from being encountered by the user. One trick to avoiding user frustration is to make it hard for them to make an error during data entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expanding on jfrankcarr's comment a bit:

I would consider Oracle error messages like this an exception - normally I'd code the application to do all the validation it can before it hits the database, and give user-friendly error messages.

Oracle then becomes a "safety net" which ensures that bad data can never get too far into the system by raising an exception if something bad slips past the application's validation. So you'd code the application to do something with any Oracle error - e.g. log it, send it to IT Support, and show a "system error" message to the user or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
raise_application_error (-20001,'You have tried to insert a duplicate supplier_id.');
```

I have never worked on front end so not sure how you will catch it there. This is example where you are trying to catch duplicate entry like this you need to catch all exception. *But limitation for this is, it will work only on PL-SQL.*

Another option is front end validation before you connect to oracle. But this will slows down performance.

Comment: In my experiences, front end validation results in a performance *gain*, because you don't have to do as many round-trips to the database. But YMMV of course.

Comment: Front-end validations are not always fool-proof as well, as they are limited by read consistency to not seeing other uncommitted changes, so depending on the expected level of concurrency some kind of database exception handling might be needed anyway.