# Any way to intercept an error message and make more user friendly?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have looked for an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112550/how-to-convert-oracle-error-messages-to-more-user-friendly-messages) among other places but havent quite been able to find what I need to know.

I have 3 tables, Order_Details, Products_Ordered and Product_Details. The first two are being used in a master detail form to show the order and the items ordered together. The Products_Ordered  table has a composite primary key made from two foreign keys, the first being the primary key from the Order_Details table, and the second being the primary key from the Product_Details table. Together they ensure that a type of product can only be added to an order once. If someone wants to order more than one product then the quantity field in the record can be altered to reflect this. All that seems fine so far.

My issue is that when adding products to the order in the master detail form i have used a drop down list of values to select the product to add to the order. the display value for this is the product name and the return value for it is the primary key for the product from the Product_Details table.

I like this because its easier for the user to simply select the product and add a quantity of it to the table. And it works fine for both insert and update operations apart from one situation.

If the user selects the same product in to rows then submits the table the database then tries to add the product to the order twice, throwing a "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated." error. Obviously this is because of the product ID being used in the primary key of the table.

I don't want to allow the user to add two records to the table like that, rather id like to force them to alter the quantity field accordingly. The error message that comes up isn't very user friendly so my question is how can I detect this error and display a more user friendly one instead telling them to alter the quantity field instead?

*If this isn't possible then is there a way that I can hide any already selected products from the dropdown list of values in the following table rows? I haven't looked into this too much because surely it would get complicated when the user tries to add more rows than products available in the dropdown and there are no more products values to show?

I am quite new to this so please be nice. Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link where all is nicely described:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

Section
Predefined PL/SQL Exceptions
in combination with:
Defining Your Own PL/SQL Exceptions
and
Defining Your Own Error Messages: Procedure RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR

Hope it helps...